# How to classify these lines in this ASCII file

Tags: shell, shell-script

The ASCII file I have is this:

```
a
1 2 3
1223
b
1 2 3 5
3344
1223
c
1 2 34
a
4 5
c
123
```

How do I collect the lines below a,b,c respectively?

**Q:** What would I do to get the lines below?

```
a
1 2 3
1223
4 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an `awk` solution that goes out of its way to prevent printing the second `a`:

```
awk '$1 == "a" { if (!head) print; n=head=1; next } $1 !~ /^[0-9]/ { n=0 } n' ascii_file
```

Replace `"a"` with `"b"` to get those results, etc.

Output:

```
a
1 2 3
1223
4 5
```

If you wanted a loop, you could do it like this:

```
for letter in a b c; do
  echo
  awk -v letter="$letter" '$1 == letter { if (!head) print; n=head=1; next } $1 !~ /^[0-9]/ { n=0 } n' /tmp/a
done
```

which would have this output:

```
a
1 2 3
1223
4 5

b
1 2 3 5
3344
1223

c
1 2 34
123
```

(Note the `echo` line.  This delimits between each query's hits.  I structured this answer to let you query per letter, which is my understanding of the question.)

Answer (score 2):

Ah, `awk` makes things so much easier, using only one pass through the data, unlike the other solutions I've seen here so far:

```
/^[a-z]/{key=$0;} 
/^[0-9]/{if (key in res){ res[key]=res[key] "\n" $0;} else {res[key]=$0;}} 
END {for(key in res){
    print key; 
    print res[key];
    }}
```

If you want `sed`+frills-only, this appears to work:

```
 cat data.txt | sed -e '/^a/,/^[b-z]/!d' | sed -e '2,${ /^[a-z]/d }'
```

(Yes, it's a [useless use of cat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11710552/505649)  for didactic reasons, i.e. I get confused when the file is somewhere in the middle of my pipes.)

The first `sed` considers all ranges that start with a line starting `a` and end with a line starting with a letter `b-z`, inclusive. It negates that range (the `!`) and then deletes everything matched, so we're left with

```
a
1 2 3
1223
b
a
4 5
c
```

The second `sed` only looks at the range from line 2 to the end of the file (to maintain the `a` header), and within that, deletes all lines that start with a letter `a-z`, leaving only the numerical lines:

```
a
1 2 3
1223
4 5
```

To obtain a list of all your headers, I'd try `grep '^[a-z]' | sort -u`. so the whole beast is:

```
for key in $(grep  '^[a-z]' data.txt | sort -u ); do 
    cat data.txt | sed -e "/^$key/,/^[b-z]/\!d" | sed -e '2,${ /^[a-z]/d }'  ; 
done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/^[a-z]$/ { f = $1=="a" ; if (!c++) print ; next }; f'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
/^[a-z]$/{
  i=$0
  next
  }
{
  A[i]=A[i] "\n" $0
  }
END{
  for (j in A)
    print j A[j]
  }'
```

As you can see it is simplified variant of [@Ulrich Schwarz script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/189353/89144): for lines which consist just 1 lower letter take this letter as index `i` and start new line loop. Next put all remain lines (which not "consist just 1 lower letter" because it has operated before) into assotiative array `A` according to `i`ndex settled from previous part of the script with `\n`ewline separator. When script pass all lines (reach `END`) then print array `A` by `i`ndexes.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain this a bit?

Comment: @all the methods now are via awk and sed. Does anyone knows another way? Or who can indicate how to use python to solve this problem?

Comment: Nice way of dealing with the extra newline!